# Read each morse code from a string line

Tags: c++

Hi I have morse codes of string separated by spaces for example  `*** --- ***` for SOS .

Can anyone help me to read each morse code?

For the moment I am reading each character where I need to read each morse code so that I can pass morse code as a variable to other method where it returns alphabet character.

Comment: Is this homework? Please add the tag if it is, check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/32210/) out btw.

Comment: What did **you** try? Why does it fail?

Comment: ·-- ···· ·- -   ···· ·- ···- ·   -·-- --- ··-   - ·-· ·· · -·· ··--·· ([what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/))? Create a little [example](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I think OP's username says it all!

Comment: Amateur radio operators still use morse code so try asking on http://www.eham.net or http://qrz.com and you may find some help or something written already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the morse codes and their equivalent values in a map, 
split the morse string on spaces, loop over these elements and retrieve the resulting values from your map (and concatenate them together) for your final result

this is an example showing the decoded SOS '... --- ...'

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

vector<string> SplitString (string aString);
vector<string> SplitString (string aString){
  vector<string> vec;
  char * cstr, *p;
  string str = aString;

  cstr = new char [str.size()+1];
  strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());
  p=strtok (cstr," ");

  while (p!=NULL){
   vec.push_back(p);
   p = strtok(NULL," ");
  }

  delete[] cstr;
  return vec;
}

int main(){

  map<string,string> m;
  m["..."] = "S";
  m["---"] = "0";


  vector<string> v;
  string sentence = "... --- ...";
  v = SplitString(sentence);


  vector<string>::iterator it;

  cout << "Our morse (" << sentence << ") decoded to: ";
  for ( it = v.begin() ; it < v.end(); it++ ){
    cout << m[*it];
  }

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

you can fill in the other morse codes, would've taken me too much time, sorry, used SOS since it's so well known. :) 
This example is also probably not very good nor optimised nor recommended, it's been years since I came near c++. Hope it sparks some better idea in you though.

Comment: thank you for quick reply but I have tree already containing morse and associated english letter, If I had string of morse and uppercase letters because my program encodes only lower case alphabet. for example I have *** --- ***  D* something like this so my output should show :  sos De so how i can read each morse code and convert to english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to tokenize the string and use white space char as your delimiter.